# Having problem with retrieving first 5 words from input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script which functionality should be to retrieve the first 5 words from one input and type them in a second input, but it isn't working as expected.

```js
$('#review_content').on('keyup change paste click input', function () {
  
  var contentVal = $('#review_content').val();
  var contentValSplit = $('#review_content').val().split(' ');
  
  var headerValSplit = $('#review_header').val().split(' ');
  
  if(headerValSplit.length < 6) {
      if(contentValSplit.length > 6) {
          var $five = contentValSplit[0] + ' ' + contentValSplit[1] + ' ' + contentValSplit[2] + ' ' + contentValSplit[3] + ' ' + contentValSplit[4];
          $('#review_header').val($five + "...");
      } else {
          $('#review_header').val(contentVal + "...");
      }
  } 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input id="review_content">
<input id="review_header">
```

When I paste longer text (longer than 5 words) the script is just pasting the same text in the second input, but that's not how it should work. It should get only the first 5 words from the whole text and paste only them in the second input. Or if the text is smaller than 5 words, it should synchronously type the letters from the first input in the second one and stop after finishing the fifth word. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: What is the reason for having `headerValSplit.length < 6`, and why to you have `contentValSplit.length > 6` when you really don't even want it to be greater than 5?

Comment: The logic behind `contentValSplit.length > 6` was to catch if the text is actually pasted

Comment: The logic in this code is the following:

`if the header of the review is smaller than 6 words` (only then execute any code) => `then if the length of the content of the review (in words) is greater than 6` => `get the first 5 words only and paste them in the header` ELSE=> `continue pasting text in the header collected from the content untill it doesn't reach 6 words`.

Comment: Yes, that is putting in English what the code does, but that was not my question. Anyway, I see you already accepted an answer, so I will leave it at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated version:

The following code should mach all your requirements

- As long as the header does not contain 5 words
- Take the first 5 words from the content

I think your if statements were too complex, and for some reason counter working each other. Following code works with only one `if` statement to reduce complexity. Can be optimized even further (see below).

I pasted `When I paste longer text (longer than 5 words) the script` and got `When I paste longer text...` in the second input.

```js
$('#review_content').on('keyup change paste click input', function () {      
  var headerValSplit = $('#review_header').val().split(' ');
  
  if(headerValSplit.length < 6) {
      var contentVal = $('#review_content').val();
      var contentValSplit = $('#review_content').val().split(' ');
      var $five = contentValSplit[0] + ' ' + contentValSplit[1] + ' ' + contentValSplit[2] + ' ' + contentValSplit[3] + ' ' + contentValSplit[4];
      $('#review_header').val($five + "...");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input id="review_content">
<input id="review_header">
```

---

Besides that, you can also shorten this line:

```
var $five = contentValSplit[0] + ' ' + contentValSplit[1] + ' ' + contentValSplit[2] + ' ' + contentValSplit[3] + ' ' + contentValSplit[4];
```

The following would only take the first 5, and then joins them with a space in between:

```
var $five = contentValSplit.slice(0, 5).join(' ');
```

Also, the array can simply be reduced to 5 elements, in case you don't need the other elements anyway. Then it would look like this:

```
contentValSplit.length = 5;
$('#review_header').val(contentValSplit.join(' ')+ "...");
```

Comment: Creating an edit to reflect the extra explanation given in a comment in the question. Please wait for that before commenting

Comment: What a nice answer! Helped me to understand where the problem came from... Thanks a lot!